# TypeError: dtype '<class 'datetime.date'>' not understood ; while converting Date of DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, yahoo-finance

I am working on below code, takes the data from yahoo finance and plotting the data for the technical analysis of the stock.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_finance
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ticker = 'MCD'
start = dt.date(2014, 1, 1)

#Gathering the data
data = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start)


#Calc moving average
data['MA10'] = data['Adj Close'].rolling(window=10).mean()
data['MA60'] = data['Adj Close'].rolling(window=60).mean()
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
data['Date']=mdates.date2num(data['Date'].astype(dt.date))
```

Got this error

```
TypeError: dtype '<class 'datetime.date'>' not understood
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the date column to 'datetime.Index' format and set it as the index, the graph will be displayed. No conversion is required.try it.The setting of the library to be imported has been partially corrected.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplfinance as mpf
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ticker = 'MCD'
start = dt.date(2014, 1, 1)

#Gathering the data
data = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start)

#Calc moving average
data['MA10'] = data['Adj Close'].rolling(window=10).mean()
data['MA60'] = data['Adj Close'].rolling(window=60).mean()
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
# data['Date']=mdates.date2num(data['Date'].astype(dt.date))
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

[image]